# Woocommerce hook that fires after a product is updated via REST API

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using this hook to run some code after the product is updated:

```
add_action( 'updated_post_meta', 'attach_variation_images_on_product_save', 10, 4 );
function attach_variation_images_on_product_save( $meta_id, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value ) {
    if ( $meta_key == '_edit_lock' ) { 
        if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'product' ) {
           //do something
        }
    }
}
```

This is working as expected, the function is executed after the product is updated. I want to run the same function when a product is getting updated via the REST API. I hooked my function to `woocommerce_rest_insert_product_object` like this but it did not work:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_rest_insert_product_object', 'attach_variation_images_on_product_update_via_rest', 10, 3 ); 
function attach_variation_images_on_product_update_via_rest( $post, $request, $true ) {
    if ( get_post_type( $post ) == 'product' ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $post );
        //do something
    }
}
```

Am I not using the right hook? Is there another hook I can use?

EDIT 1: It seems that my code was not running because `get_post_type($post)` is type of `post` and not `product`. I am trying to attach an image to variations using `add_post_meta($variation_id, '_thumbnail_id', $image_id);` inside a loop. It seems the function `attach_variation_images_on_product_update_via_rest( $post, $request, $true )` is executed till the end but it does not attach the image to the variations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this hook `add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'my_callback_function', 10, 1 );` that executes the callback function when you updating  products from Woocommerce back-end as well from the REST API.