# Woocommerce REST API, call function if product updated by API request

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I`m searching for action like:

```
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', function ( $post_id, \WP_Post $post, $updated ) {
        //
}, 99, 3 );
```

but fired up when the API call is sent.

So basically it should be fired up when creating, updating, deleting products, etc. by API requests.

Is there any built-in action I can use, or if there exist any endpoints that trigger hooks/actions?

Comment: If you only need to know whether it's a REST request or not, you can check if `REST_REQUEST` constants is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some research on my own, I found that there are multiple hooks reacting to API requests, like:

```
woocommerce_rest_insert_product_object
woocommerce_rest_delete_product_object
rest_api_init
```

more details here:

[Woocommerce hook that fires after a product is updated via REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49950000/woocommerce-hook-that-fires-after-a-product-is-updated-via-rest-api)